# Elmah For other PHP

Tags: php, symfony1, elmah, error-logging

Is there an [Elmah](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs) equivalent for PHP in general, Symfony in particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony comes with a logging framework that can log to file or any other backend you care to give it. From my understanding of Elmah this is about as close as you can get - there's nothing with all the features available and integrated with frameworks such as Symfony.

Please [see this chapter](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/16-Application-Management-Tools) in the Symfony book for more information on Symfony's logging capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/) can be used for PHP as well. We focus primarily on .NET, but some of our users use it for PHP as well. Take a look at the following example to start logging errors from PHP to elmah.io: https://github.com/elmahio/other-language-examples/blob/master/PHP/Logger.php

*To make it clear, I'm the founder of elmah.io and elmah.io isn't affiliated with ELMAH in any way. We share the name, but the services are very different.*

Answer (score 1):

`error_log()` writes to system log etc.

You can search in [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/packages.php) as well...

Comment: +1 for error_log  I wish I knew about it earlier before I went and rolled my own

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [PEAR::Log](http://pear.php.net/package/Log) as recommended by @Jet, along with [set_error_handler()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [set_exception_handler()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).